# Redirected to Page with selected url parameter

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

Hey Guys i have url page like this

```
http://localhost/skripsi3/web/pesananwaiting.php?pilih=13
```

There is an button inside the table and the code like this

```
echo "<a href='considered.php?idorder=" . $row['id_order']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-default btn-sm'>Considered</button></a>";
```

if i clicked the button, it will redirect to considered.php. To do update query and this is my considered.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connectdb.php";

$idorder = $_GET["id"];
$cons = "Considered";

$query="UPDATE `preorder` SET `statuspesanan`='$cons' WHERE `id_order`='$_GET[idorder]'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
header("Location:pesananwaiting.php");
?>
```

My problem is how to make header back to pesananwaiting.php with paramater like this

```
pesananwaiting.php?pilih=13
```

Thank You

Comment: I just want to point out your considered.php scrip is vulnerable to code injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `$_GET['pilih']` together with `$_GET['idorder']` through the button.

```
echo "<a href='considered.php?idorder=" . $row['id_order'] . "&pilih=" . $_GET['pilih'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-default btn-sm'>Considered</button></a>";
```

Then, echo `$_GET['pilih']` in `pesananwaiting.php`:

```
header("Location:pesananwaiting.php?pilih=" . $_GET['pilih']);
```

Comment: Hey @luweiqi Thank You very much.. it works like a charm!!